# File uploader in asp.net not showing file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Answer in C# would also help me.

I have two file uploaders in my page in which i have to do validations.

First fileuploader is for .doc or docx file and second one is for ppt or pptx file.

Following is the code:

```
 If fuAttachmentDoc.HasFile = True Then
            If Not UCase(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuAttachmentDoc.FileName)) = ".DOC" Then
                If Not UCase(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuAttachmentDoc.FileName)) = ".DOCX" Then
                    gc.ShowErrorMsg("Please Select DOC File")
                End If
            End If
        Else
            gc.ShowErrorMsg("Please Select DOC File")
        End If

        If fuAttachmentppt.HasFile Then
            If Not System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuAttachmentppt.FileName) = ".PPT" Then
                If Not System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuAttachmentppt.FileName) = ".PPTX" Then
                    gc.ShowErrorMsg("Please Select PPT File")
                End If
            End If
        Else
            gc.ShowErrorMsg("Please Select PPT File")
        End If
```

If i select file in only one file uploader i.e. if only for doc file or only ppt file uploader then it makes `fuAttachmentDoc.HasFile=true` or `fuAttachmentppt.HasFile=true` otherwise if i select two files then it keeps both as false and does not enters into condition.

I am not able to understand why is this happening.

Please help me.

Answer in C# would also help me.

Comment: used it but not working with it also

Answer (score 3):

File Uploader was not accepting file with size 0 kb .

Once i entered some random text within it, it started taking values,

fileuploderdoc.hasfile became true.